# map building with rgbslam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ubuntu 11.04, electric and kinect with openni.

I want to build 3D indoor map.

So I read the rgbslam (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

But I don't know how to use it.

How to create maps using rgbslam?

Or Do you know other way??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39032/map-building-with-rgbslam/) by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-17

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-17**:
What's wrong with the instructions under the usage section? Did you try them out? http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#Usage

**Comment by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on 2012-07-17**:
To start RGBDSLAM launch
" roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch"  I see the rgb and depth image. After, I don't know what to do. how to process the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Lorenz said, [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#USAGE_with_GUI) contains the information you need.

This is quoted form the page:

> To capture models either press space
> to start recording a continuous stream
> or press enter to record a single
> frame.

I  have tried rgbdslam before so this should work for you.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1